# Databricks autoloader methods: file notifications vs directory listing

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

When using databricks autoloader functionaliy, you can either choose file.notifications method or the default directory listing method.

I realise that the file.notifications is the superior method and that having azure functions and event grids identify file updates will mean that the solution will scale out "infinitely" and so on (I've also read that this is the recommended method in prod?). But I have a use case where the frequency of incoming files is quite small and am wondering if I can just use the directory listing method in Prod environment as well. Has anyone used directory listing method in autoloader in prod? Any thoughts/concerns? The idea at the moment is to start with directory listing method and then to switch to file notifications method as we start ingesting more files and more frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Directory Listing Mode:**
Auto Loader locates new files in directory listing mode by listing the input directory. With the exception of having access to your data on cloud storage, directory listing mode enables you to rapidly start Auto Loader streams.
Auto Loader can automatically determine whether files are arriving to your cloud storage with lexical ordering in Databricks Runtime 9.1 and later. This drastically reduces the number of API calls necessary to discover new files.
The hazards connected with directory listings have long been observed. Directory listings allow the Web user to see the majority (if not all) of the files in a directory, as well as any lower-level subdirectories, despite small information leakage. Directory listings offer far more open access than the "guided" experience of browsing a collection of prepared pages. Even a casual Web browser could gain access to files that shouldn't be made available to the public depending on a number of variables, including the rights of the files and directories as well as the server's settings for authorised files.

**File Notification Mode:**
In your cloud infrastructure account, file notification and queue services are used in file notification mode. A notification service and queue service that subscribe to file events from the input directory can be automatically set up by Auto Loader.
For big input directories or a high volume of files, file notification mode is more efficient and scalable, but it requires additional cloud permissions to set up.
For improved scalability and quicker performance as your directory grows, you might want to switch to the file notification mode.